# Does resistor affect current source's current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, current-source, voltage-source

[image: (Assume source is ideal)]

KCL? But,
Will the current I2 change if the resistance R1 is increased or decreased if yes then Why it is said that resistor in series with current source can be neglected. And if No then what if R1 is replaced with an insulator then obviously current does not even flow. And about I1 which comes from unknown circuit N1 can a current add to current source (isn't I1 =0).
And if 10 ohm resistor were doubled would'nt current I2 have been doubled?

Comment: I1 is 3A.  There are 3 A flowing through R1 regardless of its value.  (An open circuit is not allowed with an ideal current source).  Can you work out the answer from that?

Comment: Yes but isn't resistance suppose to oppose current, if the value of R is not infinite lets say 10,000+ ohms wouldn't it give current source some extra trouble to pass current through it.

Comment: Remember that it's an ideal current source.  No matter how high the resistance is, the source will push 3 A through it.  The voltage can go as high as necessary to get that 3 A.  A real-world current source of course will have limitations.

Comment: Ideal current sources trump series resistors. Ideal voltage sources trump parallel resistors.

Comment: @Adyy Consider the voltage across the current source. It can be any value at all. It's not specified. The voltage across the series resistor *is specified* because the current through it is known. So the current source merely adjusts its own voltage to fit circumstances. If the circumstances specify something specific, it just adjusts its own voltage. So the series resistor really only impacts the current source voltage and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Constant Current Sources: It does not matter what else is going on in a circuit. the current in a current source will stay the same no matter what. One exception  - Two constant current sources in series is undefined...won't work.
2. > Why it is said that resistor in series with current source can be neglected.

In electronics, elements in series must have the same current (must have). This is a consequence of conservation of charge. It's a rule. So R1 has no effect on the current entering the junction of R1 and the 10 ohm resistor.

3. > what if R1 is replaced with an insulator then obviously current does not even flow.

Current sources have a maximum voltage limit called the compliance voltage. Increasing R1 enough will reach the compliance voltage. Don't let this distract you from the problem. Let the compliance voltage be as high as is necessary to maintain I1 as a constant current

4. > And about I1 which comes from unknown circuit N1 can a current add to current source (isn't I1 =0).

Currents in parallel can add. Currents sources in series are undefined. Elements in series must have the same current. The current source I1 **defines** the current coming from N1. This is just another distraction.

5.>And if 10 ohm resistor were doubled would'nt current I2 have been doubled?

After you answer the original question then revisit this one. Again this is just a distraction. It is an interesting question, but first things first,